# Master page button Click problem from  keyboard enter button

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

In my application i have master page and content page.In my master have search text box and button, my content page is log in page.So when i fill the username and password ,click enter from key board it will take action for master page search button and redirect search page.

The master page contain user control for search button & text box and for the log in page i used image button

Plz help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code, and if so is there a problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#ctl00_top_header_txtHKeyword').keypress(function(e) {
              if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
                  $('#ctl00_top_header_btnSearchNav').click();
                  return false;
              } else {
                  return true;
              }
          });
          $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword').keypress(function(e) {

              if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {

                  $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit').click();
                  return false ;
              } else {
                  return true;
              }
          });
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your page (not the masterpage) you should be able to set a default object to fire on the enter key press.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="Button1">
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply in the content page don't have form tag and i am using image button in log in page

Comment: you definitely need a form tag

Comment: My apologies, didn't see that it was MVC. Since it's not a webform, you may want to reference [link](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/01/setting-default-button-in-aspnet-mvc.html) to mimic this behavior. As it stands you'd have to adjust the code to work with your imagebutton.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a good idea to also include a "Submit" button on a login form. If you do so, the only button becomes default and will be clicked when the user hits enter.

otherwise use some javascript as noted [here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/index_famsupp_157.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code the master page to do the search only when the currently focused element is the search text box.